# ImportError : No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, centos, mod-wsgi

Below is the snap from error log

```
mod_wsgi (pid=12320): Target WSGI script '/var/www/firstweb/firstweb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=12320): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
'/var/www/firstweb/firstweb/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/firstweb/firstweb/wsgi.py", line 6, in ?
   import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Configuration : Python 2.7.11 + CentOs 5.11 + Django 1.8 + mod_wsgi 3.5

> Its is showing Internal Server Error 
>   and from Import error from error log

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/firstweb'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'firstweb.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wgsi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: show your wsgi.py file

Comment: Is your Django librairy installed in a directory that is in one of the paths for Python modules? You can test by launching a Python shell and try ``import django.core.wsgi``.

Comment: @Tony I did that and its working fine in shell.

Comment: @PrashantShukla: Are you sure about the contents of the wsgi.py file you posted? Where is the line "from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application" mentioned by the error message?

Comment: add sys.path.append('<PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV>/Lib/site-packages') to wsgi.py and try

Comment: This won't fix the error, but you should use `get_wsgi_application()` rather than `WSGIHandler()`.

Comment: @knbk I've tried that but their wasn't any change.

Comment: @Anoop I'm not using virtual env